# Can not authenticate via Yammer oauth when bundled with Office 365

Tags: oauth, yammer

I'm trying to reproduce an issue some of our customers are experiencing by not being able to authenticate our app with Yammer via Oauth. When they attempt to authenticate, we just get "Oauth Failure", but no other information.

The common trait among all of them is that they all have Office365 subscriptions with Yammer.

We recently purchased Office365 E3 enterprise plan and upgraded our Yammer network accordingly. Our Yammer network now has the Office 365 toolbar at the top.

We cannot reproduce the issue our customers are experiencing. I thought it might be a configuration issue such that they turned off 3rd party apps via Yammer. I turned this setting off in our Yammer network admin settings and yet I still can log in via Yammer oauth which extremely odd and potentially another separate issue perhaps.

Comment: My Yammer apps work just fine against O365-aware networks. Are you using the JS SDK? REST API? Does your code work against non-Office 365 Yammer Networks? Have you Fiddled the auth traffic?

Comment: Yes, it works with our o365-aware network as well, but not several of our customers. We're using Rest api with omniauth to handle Oauth flow.